# Varying Width of one division... and second division should adjust according to first divison

Tags: html, css

So i want something like this.

There are 2 divisions and the second onw should adjust its width according to the first one!

I have tried max-width, min-width, but i am not able to reproduce this thing. Please help me out
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's what [Tables are really good](http://jsbin.com/xowage/1/edit) at:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>Content Here</td><td><input type=text></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Content Here Changes</td><td><input type=text></td></tr>
</table>
```

otherwise if you cannot use `table` you need [some more `DIV` elements](http://jsbin.com/xowage/2/edit):

```
<div class="asTable">

  <div>
    <div>Content Here</div><div><input type=text></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Content Here Changes</div><div><input type=text></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.asTable{
  display:table;
}
.asTable > div{
  display:table-row;
}
.asTable > div > div{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: @SiddharthArora OK than, what you *can* do (before I give more suggestions) ?

Comment: @SiddharthArora ok, take a look.

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: @SiddharthArora if you did not noticed I've added links-to-demos into my answers

Comment: The width of the input text shoud be taking the whole of the right division, and it should reduce when someone changes the left text.

Answer (score 0):

See if this may help you

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="divA">
    <div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    <div class="div3">DIV 3</div>
    <div class="div4">DIV 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.div1{
    display: inline;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
.div2{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.div3{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #FF6600;
}
.div4{
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sgr8646f/1/

Comment: Thanks but man, your division 2 is of fixed width, i want it to vary as per divison 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just use float with a wrapper

```
<Div class='wrapper'>
<Div class='left'>
Content Left
</Div> 
<Div class='Right'>
Content Right 
</Div>
    <Div class='left'>
Content Left Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</Div> 
<Div class='Right'>
Content Right 
</Div>
```

Css

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
}
 .left{
float: left;
max-width: 60%;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #FF0000;
}
.right{
float: right;
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alex_crichton/19L9ddx6/1/

This had errors due to my mistyped class name but threw up two option for look and feel you can have either of the below combinations see http://jsfiddle.net/alex_crichton/19L9ddx6/5/

```
<Div class='wrapper'>
<Div class='left'>
Content Left
</Div> 
<Div class='right'>
Content Right 
</Div>
<br />
<Div class='left'>
Content Left Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</Div> 
<Div class='right'>
Content Right 
</Div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
}
.left{
float: left;
max-width: 60%;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #FF0000;
}
.right{
float: right;
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

or

```
<Div class='wrapper'>
<Div class='leftfloat'>
Content Left
</Div> 
<Div class='regular'>
Content Right 
</Div>
<Div class='leftfloat'>
Content Left Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</Div> 
<Div class='regular'>
Content Right 
</Div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
}


.leftfloat{
float: left;
max-width: 60%;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #FF0000;
```

Comment: ok look at http://jsfiddle.net/alex_crichton/19L9ddx6/5/ there are two options 
- add a line break between  the divs
- just float the stuff on the left